# SMBv2.1 without encryption seems to not be working on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, server-message-block

While we update all our Windows 7 machines to 10, we need an SMB share on a Win12R2 server to support unencrypted connections.

We have:

- Disabled SMBv1
- Enabled Encryption
- Set RejectUnencryptedAccess to false

The expected result would be:
- Windows 10 clients would default to SMBv3
- Windows 7 clients would default to SMBv2.1 w/o encryption.

However, on Windows 7, we simply can't log in when encryption is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Shockingly, I solved this!

There was another mapped drive on the same server that is NOT encrypted.
When that drive was mapped first, it seemed to confuse Windows 7.

**Solution:**

Unmap/disconnect all connections to that server

Clear all cached credentials to that server

Reboot (Not sure if totally required, but I did)

Map the new drive and it works.

From my findings, in Windows 7, you can't have multiple mapped drives to a Win2012R2 SMB server if one drive is encrypted and the other is not.